# Reorienting Thoughts Towards Virtuous Object

Tags: personal-practice, mindfulness

I noticed that if I set an intention to avoid some behaviour, I rarely follow through. I feel perhaps a mere intention based on willpower doesn't have much strength.

**Is it more effective to direct one's thoughts to a virtuous object whenever fantasies and cravings, or worries and rumination, occur? Are these cravings/worries causing the problems?**

Is *just* setting an intention mentally sometimes not adequate?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consult Vitakkasanthana Sutta: The Removal of Distracting Thoughts
https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.020.soma.html

It explains how one deals with unwholesome thoughts in several ways and 'Reorienting Thoughts Towards Virtuous Object' is one of those ways.

Comment: If I may ask, I wonder what "an object connected with skill" means in that sutta (or [Piya Tan's translation](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/1.6-Vitakka-Santhana-S-m20.pdf), "a sign connected with the wholesome")? Would that mean one of the *[anussati](http://www.buddha-vacana.org/formulae/anussati.html)*, or something else?

Comment: MN19;The Buddha said this: “Mendicants, before my awakening—when I was still unawakened but intent on awakening—I thought: ‘Why don’t I meditate by continually dividing my thoughts into two classes?’ So I assigned sensual, malicious, and cruel thoughts to one class. And I assigned thoughts of renunciation, good will, and harmlessness to the second class.

Comment: other than the mn19 explaination, my personal interpretation is that any theme conducive to development is good, including the nupassana and subjects for reflection otherwise listed throughout the Sutta.

Comment: Fwiw i think developing this practice is called developing the perception of abandoning;
(5) “And what, Ānanda, is the perception of abandoning? Here, a bhikkhu does not tolerate an arisen sensual thought; he abandons it, dispels it, terminates it, and obliterates it. He does not tolerate an arisen thought of ill will … an arisen thought of harming … bad unwholesome states whenever they arise; he abandons them, dispels them, terminates them, and obliterates them. This is called the perception of abandoning. (AN10.60)

Answer (score 0):

There are no virtues objects. However, the object of meditation is to bring the mind to a neutral object such as breath hence no unwholesome thoughts arise.